# Custom UITableView separator displays correctly when view loads but defaults to unwanted behaviour when cell scrolls out of view and back

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom separator that I am implementing in my `TableViewController` and want to have it hidden for the last row in each section due to it offsetting the display of my custom section header.

I am using a prototype cell in my storyboard which is of type `TableViewController` and the cell is implementing the `SessionTableViewCell` identifier.

I also have a custom `SessionTableViewCell` class but this is empty at the moment.

The problem I am experiencing is that the current code works when the `TableView` loads but when scrolling to another section and back the separator is then again applied to the last cell.

I believe the problem lies in the reuse of the cell in this method but I have also tried to create the separator in my `SessionTableViewCell` subclass and then referring to it in my `TableViewController` but the same behaviour still exists.

**SessionTableViewController.swift**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SessionTableViewCell") as! SessionTableViewCell

    cell.sessionStartLabel.text = sessionData[indexPath.row].start
    cell.sessionEndLabel.text = sessionData[indexPath.row].end
    cell.sessionScoreLabel.text = sessionData[indexPath.row].score

    let screensize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let separatorHeight = CGFloat(7.0)
    let customSeparator = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.bounds.size.height - separatorHeight, width: screensize.width, height: separatorHeight))
    customSeparator.backgroundColor = Config.tableViewBackgroundColor
    cell.addSubview(customSeparator)

    let rowsInSection = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)
    let lastRowInSection = rowsInSection - 1

    if indexPath.row != lastRowInSection {
        customSeparator.isHidden = false
    } else {
        customSeparator.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separator is getting added again and again.
When you are trying to hide the separator its hiding the recently added separator view.
Create your separator in `awakeFromNib()` of `SessionTableViewCell` and add the property `customSeparator` as the instance var of `SessionTableViewCell`.
It should work fine.

Comment: Thanks! This is the correct solution. Following your advice I created the `customSeparator` in `SessionTableViewCell` and added the instance variable to the same class. Then in the `SessionTableViewController` in `cellForRowAt indexPath:` I find the last cell in the section and put `cell.customSeparator.isHidden = true`. One more question regarding SO. Should I post the complete solution as an answer to my own question or edit my initial post?

Comment: you can update your question with the tag **Solved**

Answer (score 0):

I think I get your problem, and would suggest an alternative:

> You could set the section footer to an empty frame. `CGRectZero`
>   I've implemented a similar scenario with table footers.
>   I'm sorry I'm new to swift and will try and post some swift code later.
>   In the mean time you could try something similar to:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work. The tableFooterView is not being displayed either way so it will not solve the issue of the custom separator appearing when the view scrolls even though it behaves correctly when the view loads.

Comment: Or another way would be to check if the cell about to be displayed is the last in the section, in `cellForRowAt indexPath:` check if indexPath.row == numberOfRowsInSection. if `YES` , set the `cell` 's layer.borderColor to clearColor.

Comment: Thanks. I am already checking for the last cell in the section and as I mentioned in my question, it works when the table loads but changes to include the custom separator on all cells when the sections scroll out of view. I think I need a solution to prevent the reusable cell from this behaviour.

Comment: The separator style for a cell is set by the tableView and **not** by the cell itself. So you would have to set the tableView's separator style to None (for the last cell). This will effect the entire tableView, setting the separator style as None for all cells. So setting a different separator style for the last cell might not work in when table is Dynamic. Hope my response helps. I could be wrong. But if you do get a solution, please remember to Answer  your own question, so that it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Comment: Same as the answer by @Prashant. Thanks but this is not the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Remove custom separator before add

```
let customeView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(200) as! UIView
if customeView != nil
{
    customeView.removeFromSuperview()
}
let screensize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let separatorHeight = CGFloat(7.0)
let customSeparator = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.bounds.size.height - separatorHeight, width: screensize.width, height: separatorHeight))
        customSeparator.backgroundColor = Config.tableViewBackgroundColor
customSeparator.tag = 200
cell.addSubview(customSeparator)
```

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what I was looking for. I marked another answer as the solution and commented on how it was implemented.